# Deserialization error only on remote IIS

Tags: json, wcf, iis, serialization

When executing an ajax call to a WCF on my local IIS it works fine. The json object i send is the following:

```
    var entity = {};
    entity.LogicalName = "new_subsidiedossier";
    entity.Id = "63772FDA-9B0A-E511-8270-005056B04A46"; 
    entity.Attributes = [
        { key: "new_aantalurenperdeelnemer", value: { __type: "Decimal:http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts", Value:  11.3 } }
    ];
```

With the exact same call i just change the url to our production server. It has the same version of the WCF but only on https. This fails with 'Bad Request' and the following description:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'There was an error deserializing the object of type TamSys.Integration.Contract.Models.UpdateRequest. Input string was not in a correct format.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver) at System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName) at

Anyone experienced this before?

Regards